# Regex expression to check if there is either trailing or leading whitespace

Tags: python, regex, python-re

How can I build an expression which checks if the string has either a leading or trailing whitespace?

Currently I am trying it this way, but it's not efficient:

```
import re

entity = "Robin"
start_re = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(entity, data['text'])]

start = []
start_re = [2, 9, 72]

if len(entity.split()) == 1:
    for start_index in start_re:
        end = start_index + len(entity)
        # start_index = start_index - 1
        if data['text'][start_index - 1:end] == " " + entity:
            start.append(start_index)
```

Comment: Just use `if data['text'].startswith(' ') or data['text'].endswith(' ')`

Comment: Or even better way to do this is `if data["text"].strip(" ") != data["text"]:`

Answer (score 0):

`r'^\s+|\s+$'` should work:

```
import re 


print(bool(re.search(r'^\s+|\s+$', ' Robin')))
print(bool(re.search(r'^\s+|\s+$', 'Robin ')))
```

Comment: where should I place 'Robin' in this regular expression? because I want to find the entire phrase "Robin " or " Robin" along with the whitespace.  This is finding only the whitespace from a text right

Comment: Before and after the pipe: `r'^\s+Robin|Robin\s+$'`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regular expression.

```
import re
re.findall(r'[ ]{1}\w+[ ]{1}',a)
```

where "a" is string you want to validate. this will written null if there is no trailing or leading blanks